Boost ASIO Proxy mode + Client server mode
I have a proxy implementation using Boost ASIO, where the proxy connects to the server only when a client connects to avoid synchronization issues. The new requirement is to allow data transfer from the server to the proxy even when no client is connected. This data should be forwarded to the client once it connects. Does this still align with the proxy mode, or would a different approach be needed to handle this use case? How can we adapt the current implementation with minimal changes, or would it require a new design and major code modifications? Could we implement two modes—one where the proxy connects based on a client connection, and another where the proxy connects to the server directly (client mode)? This would allow us to have two separate connections with the server, one for proxy mode and another for client mode, enabling us to consume specific data from the server regardless of the client connection. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.


Example code and design approach used for the proxy implementation (credits to Sehe).
=============================================================
#include <boost/asio.hpp>

#include <iostream>

using namespace std::placeholders;
namespace asio = boost::asio;
using asio::ip::tcp;
using error_code = boost::system::error_code;
using socket_t   = tcp::socket;

struct Settings {
    struct endpoint {
        std::string host;
        uint16_t    port;

        friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, endpoint const& ep) { return os << ep.host << ":" << ep.port; }
        // conversions
        tcp::resolver::query query() const { return {host, std::to_string(port)}; }
        operator tcp::endpoint() const { return {asio::ip::address::from_string(host), port}; }
    } remote, local;
};

class Bridge : public std::enable_shared_from_this<Bridge> {
  public:
    Bridge(socket_t downstream_socket) : down(std::move(downstream_socket)) {}
    ~Bridge() { std::cout << __FUNCTION__ << " " << down_up << "/" << up_down << std::endl; }

    void start(Settings::endpoint const& upstream) {
        res.async_resolve(
            upstream.query(),
            [=, this, self = shared_from_this()](error_code ec, tcp::resolver::results_type eps) {
                if (ec)
                    std::cout << "Could not resolve upstream (" << upstream << "): " << ec.message()
                              << std::endl;
                else
                    asio::async_connect(
                        up, eps, [this, self = shared_from_this()](error_code ec, tcp::endpoint /*ep*/) {
                            if (!ec) {
                                up_down.start(self);
                                down_up.start(self);
                            } else {
                                std::cerr << "Connect: " << ec.message() << std::endl;
                            };
                        });
            });
    }

  private:
    socket_t down, up{down.get_executor()};
    tcp::resolver res{down.get_executor()};

    struct Pump {
        using Ref = std::shared_ptr<void const>;
        Pump(socket_t& source, socket_t& dest) : src(source), dst(dest) {}

        void start(Ref self) {
            sep = src.remote_endpoint();
            dep = dst.remote_endpoint();
            std::cout << "Starting pump " << *this << std::endl;
            pump(self);
        }

      private:
        void pump(Ref self) {
            src.async_read_some(
                asio::buffer(buf), [=, this](error_code ec, size_t n) {
                    bool const eof = (ec == asio::error::eof);
                    // std::cout << "Read(" << n << ") " << *this << ": " << ec.message() << std::endl;
                    if (!ec || eof) {
                        async_write(dst, asio::buffer(buf, n), [=, this](error_code ec, size_t) {
                            if (eof) {
                                dst.shutdown(socket_t::shutdown_send, ec);
                                std::cout << "Shutdown " << *this << ": " << ec.message() << std::endl;
                            } else if (!ec)
                                pump(self);
                        });
                    } else {
                        dst.shutdown(socket_t::shutdown_send, ec);
                        std::cout << "Shutdown " << *this << ": " << ec.message() << std::endl;
                    }
                });
        }

        socket_t &             src, &dst;
        tcp::endpoint          sep, dep;
        std::array<char, 4096> buf;
        friend std::ostream&   operator<<(std::ostream& os, Pump const& d) { return os << "(" << d.sep << " -> " << d.dep << ")"; }
    } up_down{up, down}, down_up{down, up};
};

class Acceptor {
  private:
    Settings      cfg_;
    tcp::acceptor acc_;

  public:
    Acceptor(auto ex, Settings cfg)
        : cfg_(std::move(cfg))
        , acc_(ex, {asio::ip::address::from_string(cfg_.local.host), cfg_.local.port}) //
    {
        acc_.listen();
        accept_loop();
    }

  private:
    void accept_loop() {
        acc_.async_accept(make_strand(acc_.get_executor()), [this](error_code ec, socket_t s) {
            if (!ec) {
                std::cout << "New session from " << s.remote_endpoint() << std::endl;
                std::make_shared<Bridge>(std::move(s))->start(cfg_.remote);
                accept_loop();
            } else {
                std::cerr << "Error: " << ec.message() << std::endl;
            }
        });
    }
};

int main() {
    std::cout << "Proxy started." << std::endl;
    Settings cfg {
        .remote = {"127.0.0.1", 3306},
        .local = {"127.0.0.1", 9000},
    };

    std::cout << "cfg.local  = " << cfg.local << " cfg.remote = " << cfg.remote << std::endl;

    asio::io_context ioc;
    Acceptor proxy(ioc.get_executor(), cfg);
    ioc.run();
}

